# Слушатели событий

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Прочитал недавно, что устанавливать слушателей событий в методе onResume() и отсоединять в onPause является хорошим тоном. Не совсем понятно, почему именно так? Ведь есть сборщик мусора, который сам решает, что нужно уничтожить. И если много разных слушателей, это займет какую-то часть памяти, да и не очень удобно будет.

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем суть?

Comment: Сборщик может не успеть, и получишь NullPointerException. Плюс ссылки на объект в других объектах могут помещать сборщику почистить память. В таком случае может случится утечка (например, сборщик не сможет удалить объект activity, если ссылка на него хранится в объекте с более длительным жизненным циклом).

Comment: Я вроде читал, что создание слушателей без явных ссылок на них (то есть внутренними классами, inline) это шорошо, и можно не париться на этот счет, если делать так. В этом случае ссылка на слушатель будет только у самого объекта, которому этот слушатель установлен.

Comment: @metalurgusт.е. если класс реализует интерфейс, onClickListener например, то в onPause надо его отсоединять. 
А если в классе OnClickListener click = new OnClickListener(...
то во втором случае ничего делать не нужно ?

Comment: прочтите вот это http://habrahabr.ru/company/sebbia/blog/243537/